# How to embed Ruby in C++?

Tags: c++, ruby, scripting, embedded-language

What's the best way to embed Ruby as a scripting language in C++? Using ruby.h? SWIG? Something else? What I need is to expose some C++ objects to Ruby and have the Ruby interpreter evaluate scripts that access these objects. I don't care about extending Ruby or accessing it in C++.

I've found this [article on embedding Ruby in C++](http://aeditor.rubyforge.org/ruby_cplusplus/index.html), and while it's very useful, it's kinda old and I was wondering if there are any other resources on the subject (or open source implementations of similar engines).

Comment: You can use `mruby` https://github.com/mruby/mruby now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

swig is probablly the way to go.....  but ruby doesnt embed too well......

if you want a language that embeds nicely into C++, try lua

Comment: I did try lua, it's a wonderful language and was pretty easy to embed. Ruby is a requirement however, as I already have a lot of existing Ruby code I'd like to reuse.

Comment: Yes even don#t try to embedd ruby and use it from a single thread in you multithreaded apps. They (the ruby programs) are changing signal handlers, envionrment variables, current directories etc. all the time.

Comment: I realize this answer is half a decade old, but I should mention that Ruby is my favorite language to embed among JS, Lua, and Python. To those that might hesitate, I suggest reading http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html and trying a small example before dismissing it.

Comment: I haven't looked at it for a long time,  how does it handle multitasking?  its big limitation was rubys implementation had a lot of globals meaning if you embed it and use it from multiple threads you get problems, as opposed to lua which was designed specifically  to handle that situation.

Answer (score 11):

[Rice](http://jasonroelofs.github.io/rice/) is looking very promising.

Comment: Note to Windows users: Rice is only known to properly compile and run under Cygwin and Mingw. :(

Answer (score 6):

Ruby provides a very helpful README.EXT file.  It has lots of information about how to extend Ruby, and convert between C & Ruby types.

There is also this [excerpt](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ext_ruby.html) from the [pick axe book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974514055) which pretty much covers the same thing.

In my case, when I added Ruby scripting to my application I decided against using swig, because my needs were very simple, and I didn't want to add yet another build dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You might wish to check out [tinyrb](http://code.macournoyer.com/tinyrb/).

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on Rarity (https://github.com/Plaristote/Rarity), which does two things:

- Generates Ruby bindings from a YML description of your C++ API
- Allows interaction with Ruby script in the most C++ fashion there is

I've solved a good deal of question (exception handling, garbage collection)...
I haven't seen anywhere else the code generation that Rarity uses to make your bindings come to life. I also haven't seen any other lib that allows such an easy conversion between C++ and Ruby types.

I think Rarity's worth the shot ! And I'd be glad to have some feedback as well :) !