# Embedding Ruby, calling a function from C

Tags: c, ruby, linux, embedded-ruby

I'm writing an app that calls ruby code from c. I am having a little difficulty and wondered if anyone could point me in the rite direction.

I currently have in my C.

```
#include ruby.h

main()
{
  ruby_init();
  rb_require("myRubyFile");
  rb_funcall(rb_module_new(), rb_intern("RubyFunction"), 0, NULL);
}
```

My ruby file is in the same directory as my c file and is called myRubyFile.rb and contains a definition of the function RubyFunction().

This is a cut down of what I actually want to do, just making it more readable for others. I just require some feedback as to whether this is the correct method to call ruby code from my c file.

Regards

Comment: Quick suggestions:  1) don't omit ruby_init_loadpath() (I SEGV without this), 2) don't name the method `RubyFunction` -- when called without parens ruby will look for a *constant* of the same name, and, 3) you probably want a "static" method defined in an application-specific class or module, not one def'd against the implicit `self` (see answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
extern VALUE rb_vm_top_self(void); /* Assumes 1.9.  Under 1.8, use the global
                                    * VALUE ruby_top_self
                                    */
...
rb_funcall(rb_vm_top_self(),           /* irb> RubyFunction()                   */
           rb_intern("RubyFunction"),  /* irb> self.RubyFunction() # same thing */
           0,
           NULL);
```

**Longer answer:**

The first argument to `rb_funcall` is the *receiver* of the method call.

Assuming you `def`ined `RubyFunction()` outside of any explicit class or module context, then it is added to the eigenclass of the implicit, *main object at the "top level" of every ruby vm*.

In ruby, this object is accessible as the top-level `self`:

```
$ cat myRubyFile.rb
# file: myRubyFile.rb
def foo
  puts "foo"
end

$ irb
irb> require "myRubyFile"
=> true
irb> foo
foo
=> nil
irb> self.foo()    # same thing, more explicit
foo
=> nil
irb> self
=> main
```

In C under 1.9 it is accessible as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use the following approach:

Basic struct to share data

```
typedef struct ruby_shared_data {
    VALUE obj;
    ID method_id;
    int nargs;
    VALUE args[4];
} ruby_shared_data;
```

Create a function for call ruby objects on some part of your code

```
static VALUE ruby_callback(VALUE ptr) {

    ruby_shared_data *data = (ruby_shared_data*)ptr;

    return rb_funcall2(data->obj,data->method_id,data->nargs,data->args);
}
```

On some part of your code...

```
    ruby_shared_data rbdata;

    rbdata.obj = obj;
    rbdata.method_id = rb_intern("mycallback");
    rbdata.nargs = 1;
    rbdata.args[0] = rb_str_new2("im a parameter");

    int error = 0;
    VALUE result = rb_protect(ruby_callback,(VALUE)&rbdata,&error);

    if (error)
            throw "Ruby exception on callback";
```

Is always a good idea to wrap rb_funcall with rb_protect.

Another interesting thing is to know the parameters of the callback, one approach is the following

```
ruby_shared_data rbdata;

rbdata.obj = callback;
rbdata.method_id = rb_intern("arity"); 
rbdata.nargs = 0;

int error = 0;
VALUE result = rb_protect(ruby_callback,(VALUE)&rbdata,&error);

if (error)
        throw "Ruby exception on callback";

narguments = NUM2INT(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't like to call ruby from inside C unless you have complex C project which you don't want to re-build in ruby.

There are two ways to interact between C and ruby. You can extend ruby with code written in C. See [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Or you can embed ruby, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056051/how-do-you-call-python-code-from-c-code), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239315/how-to-embed-ruby-in-c) and [here](http://metaeditor.sourceforge.net/embed/).

BTW, what do you mention is "embed" ruby, not "extend" ruby.