# Run ruby script from c or c++ program

Tags: c++, c, ruby

How do i run/execute a ruby script inside a c or c++ program? instead of typing `irb` in the Terminal and then `ruby rubyfile.rb` to run it.

Normally when i want to run/execute a makefile with command "flash" i would do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

system("make flash");
```

I'm using mac by the way

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239315/how-to-embed-ruby-in-c) help you? Or maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626333/embedding-a-ruby-interpreter-in-a-c-app)?

Comment: Not really what i'm looking for

Comment: system("ruby xxxx.rb"); does it work?

Comment: What about typing "irb" to start with or it not needed in that case?

Comment: @JhsajdaHhas: Have you tried anything? Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do? Why do you want to invoke the interactive shell?

Comment: Do you actually know what `irb` does? You don’t type that before executing a ruby script.

Comment: Yes i have tried to say: system("ruby file.rb");, but it says: ruby: No such file or directory -- file.rb (LoadError)

Comment: Also tried, char cmd[1040];
char cwd[1024];
if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
{
   snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "ruby -C \"%s\" file.rb", cwd);
   system(cmd);
}

Comment: Jhasajda, type `system("pwd")`. Your program's working directory is probably not the same as where your ruby file is contained. Consider using the absolute path rather than the relative path. Also, you don't need `irb` to run a ruby program. You can just type `ruby file.rb` in the terminal (assuming `file.rb` is contained in your working directory).

Comment: Why do you write `#include <stdlib.h>` in your code snippet ? A C directive in a Ruby program ? Do you really want to run embedded Ruby from C++. I could document it, but I need to be sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function of exec function group.

```
#include <unistd.h>
exec..()  #exec function group
```

you can type

```
man 3 exec
```

in terminal,to help you.